# How to change io.sort.mb per job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am wondering if I can change the value of io.sort.mb per job? I know you can set a value for the parameter in mapred-site.xml but I want to use different values in different jobs programatically. I tried conf.setInt("io.sort.mb", someValue) but it doesn't seem to work. JVM setting has enough memory (like 2.25GB) and there is no other jobs running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just set it in the `Configuration` (`JobConf` in earlier versions) before you submit. It does work; I used it in Mahout. Make sure you are setting `conf` onto your `Job` after you set the value and before you submit. Make sure you are setting the right `conf` too! Maybe you can say how you know it isn't working.

Comment: A good question and thanks! I guess the way I used is correct but somehow I didn't see any changes in spilled records so I was suspicious something was wrong on my side. Anyway of double-checking this?

Comment: It should say in the tasktracker logs how much it has allocated, and shot messages about how many ways it's merging the output, and how many passes were needed. That should be affected by settings like this so you should see a difference for sure. Look at Mahout's `RecommenderJob` where it sets these values for an example.

Comment: From the log, I found it is indeed working but it looks like I need to increase the size a bit more. Thanks!